# Colon in bibliography keys incompatible with babel, biblatex and tex4ht

Tags: biblatex, babel, biber, tex4ht, french

Keys are labeled as `author:year` in my BibTeX file. For example, `@article{John:2000, author={John}, year={2000}, ...}`. This scheme works well with `pdftex`, `biblatex` and `mk4ht oolatex`.

But if in addition `babel` is loaded with the `french` option, then `mk4ht oolatex` cannot find any BibTeX key.

In the example below it looks for `John:{}2000` instead of `John:2000`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french, american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sample.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{John:2000,
author={John},
title={Title},
journal={Journal},
year={2000}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
La première phrase \autocite [100] {John:2000}.
\end{document}
```

By running:

```
$ latex foo
$ biber foo
$ mk4ht oolatex foo
```

I get this warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'John:{}2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.
```

My question is: whose bug is this: `tex4ht` or `babel`? Any ideas as to how to avoid it without changing my BibTeX keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because french `babel` makes colon active, it inserts space before the colon. You can switch of this behaviour with command `\shorthandoff{:}` placed at the beginning of the document. Of course, it will suppress automatic inserting of spaces before colon in the whole document.

Comment: Thanks! This workaround is enough for my present purposes. I'm aware typesetting in French requires some space before colons and semicolons, but I still don't get it why this behavior isn't suppressed when looking for keys. Well, BibTeX keys are not to be typeset at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact, that this compiles for all latex commands I can throw at it, but not for mk4ht I assume it's tex4ht. Still Babel isn't the nicest of packages and I particularly dislike this way of activating punctuation, cf https://github.com/fc7/polyglossia/issues/21 for a similar recent issue. The fault is usually with the compiler, since it should work in principle but it still provokes errors more often than necessary in my eyes.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will file a bug report against it. I wish I could help the `oolatex` branch of `tex4ht` developers somehow.