# \bibentry problem with chapterbib package

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, include, bibentry

In my document I want to create a separate bibliography for each chapter. This works fine by using the chapterbib package. However, \bibentry does not work anymore in included files when invoking the chapterbib package. The MWE shows that the full cite is present in the main document, but does not show in the chapter.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@Article{einstein1911,
 author        = "Albert Einstein",
 title         = "On The influence of gravitation on the propagation of light",
 journal       = "Annalen Phys.",
 volume        = "35",
 pages         = "898-908",
 year          = "1911"}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testchap.tex}
\chapter{light}
A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.

\include{testchap}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subfiles need to have a `\nobibliography*` command included so that `\bibentry` works.  In addition, you should really put the `\bibliographystyle` of the main file before any file inclusions.  In your case it is not too important, but if you had different styles in the subfiles it would give a problem - each of the aux files for of the included files is read by `bibtex` and so it meets multiple `\bibstyle` commands, only the first one takes effect, hence the need of ordering the main file correctly.

This all works fine for the standard book class, however with `scrbook` you can not use the `sectionbib` option of `chapterbib`.  *EDTI* See below for how to work around this

## book.cls

Main part

[image: Sample main part]

Included chapter

[image: Sample included chapter]

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@Article{einstein1911,
 author        = "Albert Einstein",
 title         = "On The influence of gravitation on the propagation of light",
 journal       = "Annalen Phys.",
 volume        = "35",
 pages         = "898-908",
 year          = "1911"}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testchap.tex}
\nobibliography*

\chapter{Light}
A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.

\include{testchap}

\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

## scrbook.cls

For `scrbook` class the above will work fine, unless you pass the `sectionbib` option to `chapterbib`.  This is because the `sectionbib` option attempts to patch the definition of `thebibliography`, but `scrbook` changes the standard definition.  However, the effect of the `sectionbib` option may be optianed by issuing

```
\KOMAoption{bibliography}{leveldown}
```

in the preamble, which switches bibliogrpahies to be sections, and then `\bib@leveldownfalse`, appropriately escaped, before the main bibliography to make this a chapter.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@Article{einstein1911,
 author        = "Albert Einstein",
 title         = "On The influence of gravitation on the propagation of light",
 journal       = "Annalen Phys.",
 volume        = "35",
 pages         = "898-908",
 year          = "1911"}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testchap.tex}
\nobibliography*

\chapter{Light}
A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\nobibliography*

\KOMAoption{bibliography}{leveldown}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{einstein1911}.\\
A regular citation: \citep{einstein1911}.

\include{testchap}

\makeatletter
\bib@leveldownfalse
\makeatother
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just want to add a comment because it took me some time to figure out what was preventing this solution from working for me. `\bibentry` is for some reason not compatible with the use of `usepackage[french]{babel}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130344/using-citep-leads-to-missing-endcsname-inserted-error