# Colon in bibtextkey

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I always use colons when denoting items in my bibliography (in a .bib file):
*Lee:05*, *Smith:11*, etc.

However, **Jabref** says that

> Some characters should not be used in bibtexkey as they are not compatible or not recommended:
> { } ( ) , \ " - # ~ ^ : ' (note the colon!)

What's the problem with the colon? Should I expect to have some issues with my bibliography because of that?

Comment: See also: [What characters are allowed to use as delimiters for BibTeX keys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408530/134144)

Comment: The answer to this question does not report any problems with the colon. Does it mean it's safe to use it?

Comment: Depending on the laguage you use, the colon could cause problems. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89016/134144

Comment: @leandriis, that's an important point, thank you! I mostly use it with English and Russian. So far there were no problems, but if any problem appears, I will know what can be the potential  reason for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two aspects to asking whether a character is safe in entry keys.

1. The character needs to be safe when it is read by BibTeX (or Biber) in the `.bib` file.
2. The character needs to be safe when it is later processed by LaTeX.

Examples of characters that are unsafe on the `.bib` side would be `,`, `=`, `{` and `}`. Those characters have special meaning in the `.bib` file syntax and cannot be used in entry keys as that would confuse BibTeX or Biber when they parse the `.bib` file.

One example of an unsafe character on the LaTeX side is `~`. `~` is absolutely fine on the `.bib` file side, but it has a special definition for LaTeX (inserting a non-breakable space). The following MWE therefore breaks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby~1980,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby~1980}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(Note that `biblatex` *can* accept entry keys with `~`.)

---

The `:` is *not* problematic on the `.bib` side of things, since `:` does not have a special meaning in the `.bib` file syntax.

Depending on your language settings, `:` either behaves as normal or has a special definition (e.g. in French). If the  colon has a special definition, it is potentially dangerous. But all bibliography and citation setups that I tested (of course I only tested the usual ones) take precautions against problems with `:`, so the following MWE compiles fine.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby:1980,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby:1980}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

A similar example also works fine with `biblatex`. Indeed, the `biblatex` examples file `biblatex-examples.bib` makes ample use of colons in entry keys.

However, the occasional problem with colons pops up from time to time, see [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis)' link [Colon in bibliography keys incompatible with babel, biblatex and tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89016/35864).

Comment: This is an ultimate answer. Thank you!